# What does "get" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Drug dealers are also anti-fragile: the crazier shit gets, the more
>   fucked up people want to get.

As you know the word "get" is a multiple meaning word. So I am confused which meaning is correct, and as a result I don't understand the meaning of the sentence. I think "get" means here:

> be/get hooked on [drug](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/drug)s.

But I'm not sure.
So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> In 2011, Nassim Taleb wrote about a concept he dubbed “antifragility.”
>   Taleb argued that just as some systems become weaker under stress from
>   external forces, other systems gain strength under stress from
>   external forces. [...] Then you have robust systems. Robust systems
>   resist change well. [...] But, Taleb says, there is a third type of
>   system, and that is the “antifragile” system. Whereas a fragile system
>   breaks down and a robust system resists change, the antifragile system
>   gains from stressors and external pressures. Start-ups are antifragile
>   businesses: they look for ways to fail quickly and gain from those
>   failures. Drug dealers are also anti-fragile: the crazier shit gets,
>   the more fucked up people want to get. A healthy love relationship is
>   antifragile: misfortune and pain make the relationship stronger rather
>   than weaker.24 Veterans often talk about how the chaos of combat
>   builds and reinforces life-changing bonds between soldiers, rather
>   than disintegrating those bonds.

Comment: ***To get [adjective]*** is often used (somewhat colloquially) with the sense of ***to become [adjective]***. In your context, ***shit*** is just a coarse replacement for non-specific ***it, things, the general situation*** - so it's effectively the "parallel construction" *the more crazy things become, the more people want to get fucked up*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is **What does “get” mean here?**
>
> The poster comments "I think "get" means here (be/get) hooked on drugs".

In this case Get is used in place of become

**the crazier shit gets .......... the crazier shit becomes**

and although the context of the sentence is drugs, shit has a more general meaning here, it is meant to mean "insane situation"

**the crazier shit gets ..........  the more insane the situation becomes**

> **crazy f-cking shit** 1) the name for something that was so insane, you just had to call it “crazy f-cking shit” [Define Anything](https://definithing.com/?s=%20crazy%20shit%20&submit=Search)

have/get your shit together

> **get** verb (START TO BE) to become or start to be:[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get)
>
> After a while you get used to all the noise.

Note I am aware that **shit is also another name for Heroin** but shit is **not used in this context here**.

However the phrase **the more fucked up people want to get** does relate to drug use

> fucked-up adjective offensive slang : intoxicated from drugs or alcohol [MERRIAM-WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fucked%20up)

To summarise The author is saying **The worse the (local) situation is the more people use drugs**

Comment: Your opening sentence is incorrect  Your final sentence is correct.  "Get" refers to drug **usage**, not drug **addiction**.  These are different things.  Edit and I'll revise my vote..

Comment: @ Andrew The opening sentence is actually quoting the information posted. I tend to do this so it is clear what exactly I am answering. Many times I have been criticised for not answering the question, When I actually have. However I appreciate your comment as I can now see I need to make this more obvious to anyone who reads my post.

Answer (score 3):

There are two forms of **get** here:

1. *"the crazier shit gets"*: as the drug-takers' situations become harder for them to handle...
2. *"the more fucked up people want to get"*: ...the more intoxicated those drug-takers want to be.

The statement is not describing drug-takers wanting to be/get hooked on drugs, it is describing them wanting to be under the immediate effects of drugs as a distraction from their negative circumstances.

The longer excerpt suggests that drug-dealers are aware of this desire to be intoxicated, so benefit from general circumstances being harder for their prospective clients (and may also actively look to worsen those circumstances to increase the demand for their products).